# compatibily versions numpy, tensorflow and sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, version

I have compatibility problems between:
Numpy-tensorflow-sklearn
I installed the latest version on anaconda prompt but when I run the code this comes out: ImportError: cannot import name 'is_numpy_dev' from 'pandas.compat'

Which versions are compatible with each other?

I installed the latest version on anaconda prompt but when I run the code this comes out: ImportError: cannot import name 'is_numpy_dev' from 'pandas.compat'